# Hide a webform a role doesn't own on the overview page

Tags: 8, webforms

For a certain role, I would display only the webforms their users own on the webform overview page (/admin/structure/webform). Is this possible?

Role 1 can see and administer all forms. Role 2 can see and administer only its forms.